# Writing an ifelse statement with a paste function in for-loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, paste

So I have 50 variables with value range from 1 to 4, and I want to count how many are 1 or 2 and how many are 3 or 4.

i.e. abc1=2, abc2=2, ... abc50=3

and the following is my code

```
#Create new variable to store the counted number to

abc.low=0
abc.high=0
```

And here is the code I am stuck at (it doesn't work)

```
for (i in 1:50){
ifelse (paste("abc",i,sep="")==1|paste("abc",i,sep="")==2, 
(abc.low<-abc.low<-1),(abc.low<-abc.low))
}

for (i in 1:50){
ifelse (paste("abc",i,sep="")==3|paste("abc",i,sep="")==4, 
(abc.high<-abc.high<-1),(abc.high<-abc.high))
}
```

I am assuming the paste function is not appropriate in what I am trying to do.

i.e)

```
abc1=3

abc1==3
#True

paste("abc",1,sep="")==3
# False
```

where the paste function should return true for my purpose.

I appreciate your input!

Comment: generally, it would be best to have these variables stored in a list rather than as individual objects.

Comment: It is possible, but can you store your variables in a `list` or a vector? Your current method does not seem very "R"-like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
table(unlist(mget(paste0('abc',1:50))))
```

- `mget` create a list of variable that `unlist` transform it a to a vector.
- `table` gives the occurrence of each value for example:

  ```
   1  2  3  4 
   14 13 13 10
  ```

Comment: An error returns: "argument "envir" is missing, with no default" regarding, I think, the mget function. Would you by chance know why? By the way, thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: Which R version are you running?(Type `version` to know which version)  I am pretty sure that  you have an old R version. Try this `mget(paste0('abc',1:50),envir=as.environment(-1))`

Comment: My R was running under version 2.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
groups = rbinom(32, n = 50, prob = 0.4)
tapply(groups, groups, length)
```

Above tapply function returns count of elements in groups